# References homotopy groups of maps and diagrams

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

In the following extract taken from the appendix of Wall's book on Differential Topology the author mentions the groups $\pi_n(j)$ associated to a map and the groups $\pi_n(\Phi)$ associated to a diagram, but he does not really define them.

> I'm looking for references (textbooks or similar) where I can find a precise definition of these groups, and more about the exact sequences.

[image: From the appendix of Wall's book.]

Comment: Not sure about the second one, though for the first, one can define $ \pi_n(j)=\pi_n(M_j,X) $ where $ M_j$ is the mapping cylinder and the rest is just the usual LES of homotopy groups.